# Unexpected value while parsing Value

Tags: json, rest

I am testing invoking a third party RESTful API via PostMan. I built a Mock version of the API using Swagger CodeGen and then invoked it using the CURL command:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:50352/MyService-end-point" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"sonoo\",\"salary\":56000,\"married\":true}}"
```

But I always get the response

```
{
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|67a5f57d-408cdcb27108b38f."
}
```

What is wrong with the message - it looks valid JSON but looks to be complaining about the { character.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have corrected the issue. The server process I was using was created as a mock service using the CodeGen feature in Swagger which I then ran as a local service using IIS Express. Swagger CodeGen created code where the type of the body was 'string', Changing this to be of type 'object' and then adding code to de-serialize the object looks to have worked.